# How to fix issue '?' character on Crystal Report 2016 when exported to PDF file

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm facing and using Crystal report 2016 connect with oracle, if i export file pdf on my local, it display unicode utf-8 (Vietnamese) normal(i use window 2010).

But if i export file on my server dev (i use Centos), it was broken and error font with character '???'
. On my centos i have install TrueType font of Microsoft Font

my version CR is 14.2.2
my error file when export:

[image]

How to fix the problem ? many thank

Answer (score 0):

Which font does the report have? And which font is the replacement font in Centos for this one? I think the replacement-font that is used in Centos doesn't support all symbols.